# My function to list prime numbers from zero to a maximum is giving me lots of extras that don't make sense

Tags: java, math, primes

Here is my current code:

```
private static int primeFinder(int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        nums.add(i + 1);
    }
    for (int currentLoc = 0; currentLoc < nums.size(); currentLoc++) {
        for (int testLoc = 1; testLoc < currentLoc - 1; testLoc++) {
            if (nums.get(currentLoc) % nums.get(testLoc) == 0) {
                System.out.println(nums.get(currentLoc) + " " + nums.get(testLoc));
                nums.remove(currentLoc);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i : nums) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run it between zero and 50, it prints out this:
1 2 3 5 7 11 13 16 17 19 23 27 29 31 35 37 41 43 47 50

Why are there extraneous solutions (16, 27, 35, 50)?

Comment: After `nums.remove(currentLoc)`, the rest of your `testLoc` loop runs on the next number in your list; then the outer loop moves on to the next number, without checking lower factors. For instance, after 15 is removed, `testLoc` is already 3, so the factor of 2 isn't checked for 16.

Answer (score 1):

As khelwood explained the inner testLoc loop doesn't exit after it's removed a number, you could implement a break into the loop. An example being the following code:

```
private static int primeFinder(int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> nums = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
        nums.add(i + 1);
    }
    for (int currentLoc = 0; currentLoc < nums.size(); currentLoc++) {
    boolean removed = false;
        for (int testLoc = 1; testLoc < currentLoc - 1 && !removed; testLoc++) {
            if (nums.get(currentLoc) % nums.get(testLoc) == 0) {
                System.out.println(nums.get(currentLoc) + " " + nums.get(testLoc));
                nums.remove(currentLoc);
                removed = true;
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i : nums) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

However, I believe a better way would be to avoid using .remove() all together. Such as the following:

```
private static int primeFinder(int max) {
    ArrayList<Integer> primes = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i= 0; i< max; i++) {
        boolean prime = true;
        for (int primeLoc= 1; primeLoc < i - 1; primeLoc++) {
            if (i % primes.get(testLoc) == 0) {
                prime = false;
            }
        }
        if(prime) {
            primes.add(i);
        }
    }
    for (int i : primes) {
        System.out.print(i + " ");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Although unrelated to the question, I don't see any point of having the function return an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Also storing the prime numbers as `ArrayList<Integer>` is not the best method.

I am using this function to generate and check prime numbers with a BitSet. This is one of the fastest java methods I know.

```
import java.util.*;

public class PrimeNumbersSieve{

     public static void main(String []args){
        System.out.println(computePrimes(50));
     }
     
    
    public static BitSet computePrimes(int limit) {
        final BitSet primes = new BitSet(limit);
        primes.clear(0);
        primes.clear(1);
        primes.set(2, limit);
        for (int d = 2; d < Math.sqrt(limit); d++) {
          if (primes.get(d)) {
            for (int m = d * d; m < limit; m += d) {
              primes.clear(m);
            }
          }
        }
        return primes;
    }
}
```